# teradata, optimization query

Tags: query-optimization, teradata

I make a request in teradata. after a while the session is terminated cpu> 100000 s

How can I optimize a query?

```
select a, b, c, d, e from table where (a = '55' or a='055') and date > '20180701'
```

Comment: It's nearly impossible to answer `why is my query slow` questions.  If you can post your explain plan, we can try to help.

Comment: Are you sure that `table` is not a view? If it is a table, include the table definition and statistics that exist on the table.

Comment: Index the table.a column for starters, and run stats on it.

Comment: Sorry, this is a view and not a table.

Comment: @Gennady If you can provide an EXPLAIN output we may be able to find something that is contributing to the resource consumption.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes are used to find rows with specific column values quickly. Without an index, MySQL must begin with the first row and then read through the entire table to find the relevant rows.

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD INDEX (a);
```

Comment: This a question for Teradata, not MySQL, and Teradata is quite fast in scanning large tables. But 100000+ CPU seconds are never caused by a simple scan of a table (even if it's Petabyte-sized).